# How to store client Certificates' public keys in Database?

Tags: sql, public-key

I am implementing Client Certificate Authentication in an asp.net application and I need to assign to each user from the table Users, the public key of his/her corresponding Client Certificate. How can I achieve this?  I am generating Client Certificates via `makecert.exe`.